# Singleton class implementation in Multi threaded environment

Tags: singleton

In Multithreaded environment where there are 50 concurrent threads are accessing a singleton object.
  Can it lead to a performance issue as there can be situation threads can be blocked as all the threads will try to access a single instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concurrent access will not be an issue. but you have to be careful with synchronization of such access. i.e. (I assume we talk about java)

```
    class MySingletonFactoryClass 
    {
       public static MySingleton getInstnace() 
       {
          synchronized(MySingletonFactoryClass.class) {
            if(instance == null)
              instance = new MySingleton();

            return instance;    

         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: what if i will create one wrapper class and my code will like this static MySingletonfactoryClass instance = MySingletonfactoryClass.getInstance();                              Still there is a chance of lock?

Comment: This is an overly complicated and ***wrong*** solution.   The above implementation creates a new instance of MySingleton by calling new. This means that MySingleton, by definition is not a Singleton, because Singleton can not have more than on instance and the above implies that almost anyone can do a new MySingleton.

Comment: @inor if you will take a second look - you will notice, that MySingleton will be created only once.

Answer (score 0):

There will not be a performance issue and you do NOT need to synchronize anything, nor wrap it in any way, just implement it the regular recommended way:

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton _instance;
    private MySingleton() {
         //initialize it here 
    }
    public static MySingleton getInstance() { return _instance; }

    //other methods of the class here 
}
```

Comment: getInstance() will always return null. it's not c++, where _instance would be constructed automatically. :)